# In Shadow DOM, override CSS body *

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I have the following scenario:

[Printscreen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMtZn.jpg)

I have a CSS in the project (which I can't change) defining the following:

```
body * {
  font-family: 'x'
}
```

And this CSS is influencing my shadow DOM, because of that, I can't use the **font-family** property without using **!important**. Only with **!Important** works:

```
::slotted(span), ::slotted(p){
    font-family: arial !important;
}
```

Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: Only thing that seems to work is remove the `*` from `body *` - even though `*` does not have any effect on specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the information needed to answer this can be found in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54974802/638544).  In summary: A document-wide style without `!important` will always override a shadow dom style without `!important`, if they apply to the same element.

(And in this case, they do apply to the same element: slotted elements exist outside the shadow dom, so `*` rules in the document stylesheet can find them.)

You've already found two workarounds to this.  I'll list them here for completeness:

**Use !important:**

This is ugly, but it does work.  Not only does `!important` override any and all non-`!important` rules, but it also overrides any `!important` rules coming from the document-wide stylesheet!

**Reduce the `body *` rule to just `body`:**

This way, the rule won't apply directly to every element - it will only apply directly to `body`, and affect every other element via inheritance.  Inherited rules can be overridden by anything, since they're only a fallback in case nothing else applies.